# South not detecting new model file in model folder

Tags: django, orm, django-south

I'm working with an existing django project that uses south. Within each app there's a models folder where models are stored in different files. I have added a new file (shown below) but when I attempt to create migration files for the model, South fails to detect the new file and says: "Nothing seems to have changed." My question is what is the correct way to get south to detect this new model? Thanks.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin



class AdgroupEmailRecipients(models.model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)


    class Meta:
         app_label = 'wifipromo'

class AdgroupEmailRecipientsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =  ('user_first_name', 'user_last_name', 'user_email')

    def user_first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.users.first_name
    user_first_name.short_description = "First Name"

    def user_last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.users.last_name
    user_last_name.short_description = "Last Name"

    def user_email(self, obj):
        return obj.users.email
    user_email.short_description = "Email"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `__init__.py` file of the models folder, you have to import the model for South or even syncdb to detect it. Basically django is just looking for one file with all your models... and if you import it all in **init**.py that's what the system will see.